# android centering image in webview

Tags: android

Im trying to add image to WebView and then scroll to image center. But `computeHorizontalScrollRange()` and `computeVeticalScrollRange()` returns 0 all the time.

```
web = (MyWebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    web.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    web.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imageParams.height = 500;
    imageParams.width = 500;
    image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
    image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    web.addView(image);
    web.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            web.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            web.scrollToCenter();
        }
    });
```

And in extended WebView class:

```
    public void scrollToCenter(){
    int cHoriz = computeHorizontalScrollRange()/2;
    int cVertic = computeVerticalScrollRange()/2;
    scrollTo(cHoriz, cVertic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..   after setting **height** and **width**

```
imageParams .addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
```

or

```
imageParams .addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);    
imageParams .addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
```